# Fetching Nested JSON in Couchbase lite in Android

Tags: java, android, couchbase

I have a nested JSON as follows which I want to store and fetch from couchbase lite in android

```
{
 "sensor":"12" ,
 "patient":"2",
 "readings": {"5090":"100" ,
              "5092":"100"}
}
```

I want to fetch value corresponding to key 5090 from my couchbase

I am able to fetch the entire  Document in couchbase using retrievedDocument.getProperties()
as

```
{_rev=1-7881f65efdcd0c119b936d4d3a734d42, sensor=12, readings={5090=100, 5092=100}, patient=2, _id=6482cee3-4267-459e-8039-860dbb5d1318}
```

I am also able to get the nested json corresponding to the key "readings" by
retrievedDocument.getProperty("readings") as

```
{5090=100, 5092=100}
```

now I need to fetch the value(100) corresponding to the nested key 5090 (inside readings)

I tried following in Java

```
retrievedDocument.getProperty("readings['5090']")
retrievedDocument.getProperty("readings[\"5090\"]")
retrievedDocument.getProperty("readings.5090")
retrievedDocument.getProperty("readings[5090]")
```

but all of them returns null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
retrievedDocument.getProperty("readings").getProperty("5090");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem now using following:

```
((Map) retrievedDocument.getProperty("readings")).get("5090"))
```